# Where can I host docker containers

Tags: docker, web-hosting

Maybe this is a trivial question, but I am new to docker and definitely not an expert on web hosting. I couldn't find the exact answer to this question on google, and this might be something that would interest a lot of other people.

What are my options for web hosting for docker containers? If docker can be run anywhere, does that mean that I can host my containerized app on LAMP shared hosting? Or do I need a VPS and set it up somehow for docker platform? I also heard about AWS providing some hosting for docker, so I am confused about what can docker be hosted on, and if someone can explain me it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker can be run in Ubuntu, Linux, recent windows server 2016 support docker.  Docker can be installed in any one of above server with bare minimum requirements. Coming to cloud hosting , cloud provides platform to manage docker container like DC/os, kubernetes etc but not docker as service. To install docker it's require vps or in on-primise server